# Jasper Reports - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleBlob when using BLOB as Detail Field

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I want to show BLOB Images in a report. But if I drop the BLOB Field into the detail band I just get the error message: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleBlob cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.2.0.final`
I added the ojdbc6.jar to the classpath of my database connection before. 
Does anybody have a solution here?

Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Helpful link: https://sourceforge.net/p/pljrxml2pdf/discussion/general/thread/30c69e33/ - This post says that you need to point to the `Oracle jdbc-driver-jar` on the `Driver classpath`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not solving my problem. I can execute the report without the BLOB's,  so the database connection works with the driver classpath. But Jasper can't find oracle.jdbc.OracleBlob which ojdbc6.jar normally should contain..

Comment: it's somehow not finding the class when you run the report (why?, not enough info in post to understand),  try with just java.sql.Blob, I guess you do not need any special method on the OracleBlob

Comment: I can't even add the BLOB field to the detail band, without the field i can run the report. I also tried java.sql.Blob, that doesn't matter. (With java.sql.Blob I get java.lang.NullPointerException when adding the field to the detail band)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had asimilar issue and the solution was to upgrade the oracle driver. I changed `ojdbc14.jar` by  `ojdbc6.jar` and the problem was solved.

Comment: The recommendation is to use the latest JDBC driver which is ojdbc8.jar from 12.2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a maven project you might be missing in your pom.xml the following:

```
    <properties>
        <ojdbc6.version>11.2.0.2.0</ojdbc6.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc6</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Class Type to java.awt.Image in the dataset for the corresponding BLOB fields. It helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).